# c# populating multiple cells from array

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

I have an array with six numbers. I'd like to perform a certain equation on each of these numbers, and then place the result in a series of textboxes, corresponding with the position within the array.
Eg. result of equation on the value of pos 0 in array goes into textbox01, result of pos1 into textbox02, etc.

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            if ((Convert.ToInt32(statArray.GetValue(i))-10)%2 == 0)
            {
                //txtMod01.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt32(statArray.GetValue(i)) - 10) / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                txtMod01.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt32(statArray.GetValue(i)) - 11) / 2);
            }
        }
```

I'd like to automatically change the name of the textbox (eg. txtMod01) to the following textbox in the series (txtMod02).

Is their any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your Textboxs in an array as well, something like:

```
    TextBox[] boxes = new TextBox[]{txtbox01, txtbox02, txtbox03, txtbox04, txtbox05, txtbox06};
    int[] values = new int[]{val1, val2,val3, val4,val5, val6};
    for(int i=0; i < values.Count; ++i)
    {
        //perform calculations

        ...

        boxes[i].Text = values[i];
    }
```

Comment: For some reason the [Array].Count didn't work for me, but as I knew exactly how many textboxes I had, it was easier to use a simple integer to define it.

This was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection, which allows you manipulate types at runtime:

```
// property name "txtMod0x"
string propertyName = "txtMod" + i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');

// get the property from the current type
PropertyInfo prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

if (prop != null)
{
    // get the property value (the TextBox in this case)
    var textBox = (TextBox)prop.GetValue(this, null);

    string val = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt32(statArray.GetValue(i)) - 11) / 2);
    textBox.Text = val;
}
```